# Wild Fly Deployment Error (Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "DemoEjb.jar" of deployment "DemoApp.ear")

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jboss, wildfly-8

i Have 4 projects [Demojpa,DEmoEjp,DEmoWEb ,DEmo.ear] 
when I run the EAR the Wild Fly Generate

> 15:17:40,241 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) HHH000230: Schema export complete
>   15:17:40,242 WARN  [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) HHH000008: JTASessionContext being used with JDBCTransactionFactory; auto-flush will not operate correctly with getCurrentSession()
>   15:17:40,588 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "DemoApp.ear")]) - failure description: {
>       "JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"DemoApp.ear\".\"DemoEjb.jar\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit.\"DemoApp.ear\".\"DemoEjb.jar\".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment \"DemoEjb.jar\" of deployment \"DemoApp.ear\"
>       Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011047: Component class devart.Example.Ejb.DefCountryEjb for component DefCountryEjb has errors: 
>   JBAS011428: Cannot inject RESOURCE_LOCAL container managed EntityManagers using @PersistenceContext"},
>       "JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
>           "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DemoApp.DemoEjb.DefCountryEjb.InAppClientContainer is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DemoApp.DemoEjb.DefCountryEjb]",
>           "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DemoApp.DemoEjb.DefCountryEjb.ValidatorFactory is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DemoApp.DemoEjb.DefCountryEjb]",
>           "jboss.naming.context.java.module.DemoApp.DemoWeb.env.\"devart.Example.Servlet.DefCountryServlet\".BllCountry is missing [jboss.deployment.subunit.\"DemoApp.ear\".\"DemoEjb.jar\".component.DefCountryEjb.VIEW.\"devart.Example.Ejb.DefCountryEjb\".LOCAL]",
>           "jboss.deployment.unit.\"DemoApp.ear\".deploymentCompleteService is missing [jboss.deployment.subunit.\"DemoApp.ear\".\"DemoEjb.jar\".deploymentCompleteService]",
>           "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DemoApp.DemoEjb.DefCountryEjb.InstanceName is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DemoApp.DemoEjb.DefCountryEjb]",
>           "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DemoApp.DemoEjb.DefCountryEjb.Validator is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DemoApp.DemoEjb.DefCountryEjb]",
>           "jboss.naming.context.java.module.DemoApp.DemoWeb.env.\"devart.Example.WebBean.DefCountryPage\".BllCountry is missing [jboss.deployment.subunit.\"DemoApp.ear\".\"DemoEjb.jar\".component.DefCountryEjb.VIEW.\"devart.Example.Ejb.DefCountryEjb\".LOCAL]",
>           "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"DemoApp.ear\".\"DemoEjb.jar\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.subunit.\"DemoApp.ear\".\"DemoEjb.jar\".beanmanager]",
>           "jboss.deployment.unit.\"DemoApp.ear\".WeldStartService is missing [jboss.deployment.subunit.\"DemoApp.ear\".\"DemoEjb.jar\".jndiDependencyService]"
>       ]
>   }
>   15:17:40,843 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS018559: Deployed "DemoApp.ear" (runtime-name : "DemoApp.ear")
>   15:17:40,844 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS014774: Service status report
>   JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
>         service jboss.deployment.subunit."DemoApp.ear"."DemoEjb.jar".beanmanager (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."DemoApp.ear"."DemoEjb.jar".weld.weldClassIntrospector] 
>         service jboss.deployment.subunit."DemoApp.ear"."DemoEjb.jar".component.DefCountryEjb.VIEW."devart.Example.Ejb.DefCountryEjb".LOCAL (missing) dependents: [service jboss.naming.context.java.module.DemoApp.DemoWeb.env."devart.Example.WebBean.DefCountryPage".BllCountry, service jboss.naming.context.java.module.DemoApp.DemoWeb.env."devart.Example.Servlet.DefCountryServlet".BllCountry] 
>         service jboss.deployment.subunit."DemoApp.ear"."DemoEjb.jar".deploymentCompleteService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."DemoApp.ear".deploymentCompleteService] 
>         service jboss.deployment.subunit."DemoApp.ear"."DemoEjb.jar".jndiDependencyService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."DemoApp.ear".WeldStartService] 
>         service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DemoApp.DemoEjb.DefCountryEjb (missing) dependents: [service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DemoApp.DemoEjb.DefCountryEjb.Validator, service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DemoApp.DemoEjb.DefCountryEjb.InAppClientContainer, service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DemoApp.DemoEjb.DefCountryEjb.InstanceName, service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DemoApp.DemoEjb.DefCountryEjb.ValidatorFactory] 
>   JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.subunit."DemoApp.ear"."DemoEjb.jar".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."DemoApp.ear"."DemoEjb.jar".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment "DemoEjb.jar" of deployment "DemoApp.ear"

and I set in EAR  Module Assembly all Project jar's